# How to implement Administration UI notifications for new revisions?

Tags: 7, nodes, notifications

I'm new to Drupal and I'm customizing an administration theme to be designed to our needs.

1. One of the things we would like to have is a visual notification of a new REVISION (content needing approval/revising/reverting, not already published). I've set this up via email, using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), but we need the visual indicator, like a red circle with the number of new revisions in it somewhere in the header.
2. Extending from that, when they click on the icon, then a page where they can administrate all the revisions needing their attention. The page would list all content types needing approval from an admin for publishing, where the admin can approve, go to the type to edit or revert to previous revision.

I thought I would have access to at least #1 via a module but cannot find something similar. Does anyone know of a module or modules that can fulfill the above requests? If the module was specifically written for something else, like notification of comments, I'm happy to rewrite it to fit - just anything that can me some time.

Comment: Check out this question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40941/how-to-create-facebook-style-user-notifications-in-d7 There are lot of useful links to tools and modules for creating some kind of message system in Drupal

Comment: Are there more references to refer to? Those are for email, granted although helpful, I wanted something a bit closer to notifications in theme to reference which would save more time. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe consider a proper workflow approach: [Workbench](https://drupal.org/project/workbench) and [Workbench Moderation](https://drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually decided on using the [Flag module](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/flag) for this since it seems less bulky than other workflow alternatives. It also allows us to use flags for other things as well and am quite happy with how easy it is to setup with [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules). I have to do code some of the display we want but it seems worth it. Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for a "*visual indicator, like a red circle with the number of new revisions in it somewhere in the header*" (as in your question), then have a look at the [Menu Badges](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_badges) module to add such notifications to any **menu item** and/or **menu tab** of your choice.

Here are some details about it (from its project page):

> Provides a method for adding iOS-style badges to menu items. (see screenshot)
>
> [image]
>
> #### Adding Badges to Menus
>
> Once enabled, go to `Administration > Structure > Menus`, and click "list links" next to the menu containing the target item. Click "edit" next to the item and select the badge to display with the Display Menu Badge select box.
>
> #### Adding Badges to Tabs
>
> For adding badges to menu tabs, there is a tab under `Administration > Structure > Menus` called "Tab Menu Badges". Search for the menu router path of the tab you want to alter, then select a badge from the corresponding select box.
>
> #### Badge Types
>
> The module includes five example badges, and new badges can be created easily with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). Modules can also supply their own badges with a hook implementation. See the [README.txt](http://drupalcode.org/project/menu_badges.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/README.txt) file for details.

Because of how it integrates with the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module, you basically reduce the solution for any type of notification to something like "Just create an appropriate view of it".

Be aware: you cannot click on those badges, though you can click on the menu links/tabs that they are related to (which is literally pretty close, no?).

#### Video tutorials:

- [Defining Menu Badges with Views in Drupal](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AoZQNg5QOI), from the module maintainer, which shows how to use it for a custom view with a menu tab "unpublished content" within `admin/content`.
- [Drupal 7 Menu Badges Module](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=iz25ED1ECv8).